unexpected status 404 (404 Not Found) with error: SubscriptionNotFound
Just wondering if can someone able to assist to share some insights and lead me where to troubleshoot and fix the error below I just came across when I ran my Terraform Apply. I have TF code where the variable is set to default: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". The intention is, If specified, identifies the landing zone resource deployment and correct placement in the Management Group hierarchy in our Azure environment.
Scripts for variable:
variable "subscription_id_landingzones" {
  type        = string
  description = "If specified, identifies the landing zone resource deployment and correct placement in the Management Group hierarchy."
  default     = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

    validation {
      condition     = can(regex("^[a-z0-9-]{36}$", var.subscription_id_landingzones)) || var.subscription_id_landingzones == ""
      error_message = "Value must be a valid Subscription ID (GUID)."
    }
}

locals {
   subscription_id_landingzones     = var.subscription_id_landingzones
}

provider "azurerm" {
skip_provider_registration = "true"
subscription_id = local.subscription_id_landingzones
   features {}
   alias = "landingzones"
}

Error Messages:
Error: populating Resource Provider cache: listing Resource Providers: loading results: unexpected status 404 (404 Not Found) with error: SubscriptionNotFound: The subscription '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' could not be found.
troubleshoot RBAC permissions, secrets expiry and terraform files

I wouldnt put a default subscription if it isnt a valid one. Have you tried removing the default?

Have you provided necessary RBAC permission to your user or SP and also check with subscription ID once @Fredevops03 refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1393750/while-building-infrastructure-in-azure-with-terraf


Unexpected status 404 (404 Not Found) with error: SubscriptionNotFound

The issue mentioned is due to is either related to wrong subscription ID or User doesn't have any RBAC permissions as per the requirement.
As per Q&ADoc it seems the user doesn't have necessary RBAC permission to read the subscription and if you're using SP the check with the environment variables defined and updated the secret if it expires and create a new secret accordingly and update it.
My RBAC permissions

Configuration:
variable "subscription_id_landingzones" {
  type        = string
  description = "If specified, identifies the landing zone resource deployment and correct placement in the Management Group hierarchy."
  default     = "98bccad1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-78dfd797ff89"

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^[a-z0-9-]{36}$", var.subscription_id_landingzones)) || var.subscription_id_landingzones == ""
    error_message = "Value must be a valid Subscription ID (GUID)."
  }
}

locals {
  subscription_id_landingzones = var.subscription_id_landingzones
}

provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = "true"
  subscription_id            = local.subscription_id_landingzones
  features {}
  alias = "landingzones"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  provider = azurerm.landingzones
  name     = "vinay-resources"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  provider                = azurerm.landingzones
  name                    = "evinayyysstorageacct"
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier            = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

Deployment:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview
azurerm_storage_account | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
Difference between various contributor roles available in Azure and how to use it effectively? - Stack Overflow by User Sridevi - Stack Overflow
